# How to extract value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to extract the first value in a cell but admittingly, I'm bad at Googling.

For example:

```
Cell A1: 25-23
Cell A2: 22
Cell A3: 21-9
Cell A4: 8-1
```

I'd like to see the results of:

```
Cell B1: 25
Cell B2: 22
Cell B3: 21
Cell B4: 8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Left with Find:

```
=--LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND("-",A1)-1,LEN(A1)))
```

The `--` changes the text string to a number.

Comment: Does it also work for a cell with a number without the "-", like cell A2?

Comment: No it will error out.  See edit

Answer (score 0):

=Left(Cell,2)

Character limits are a thing

Comment: This won't work for cell A4.

Comment: The question got edited on me - with the original dataset presented, it would work.